# upload wmv in Asset Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, video, asset-library

I created an asset library using SharePoint 2013. Then, I uploaded `avideo.mp4` and it works fine. I tried to upload a `wmv` file, it's uploaded successfully, but when I tried to play it gave me an error

> "Media failed to load".

I encoded the wmv file using Microsoft Expression Encoder and upload it again, but I got the same error!

Can anyone help me please, what should I do to make the wmv file working in the SharePoint asset library?

Answer (score 0):

I found a restriction on Microsoft Expression Encoder that says if your file is more than 10 minutes long, you will be getting this error. The only way to get it to work is to use the Pro version not the free version.

Comment: The file is more than 10 minutes! Is there an other solution so the asset library can support wmv files and I can play them?

Comment: wmv file format are very tricky and using the pro version is the only way I know to get it to work. On the other hand, you can convert it into mp4 and you should not have any problems. You can use  the FFmpeg tool (command line tool) from FFmpeg.org to convert your wmv file.

Comment: I can the FFmpeg to convert them, but I have more than 50 videos to upload in SharePoint. It will will be difficult to convert them all. Microsoft articles mentioned that wmv is a supported video format in SharePoint. I don't know why it is not working!

Comment: I converted the wmv video to mp4 using FFmpeg, then I uploaded it in my asset library. When I open it, I didn't receive an error but the video is just loading without displaying anything for a long time!

Comment: can you check the ULS logs for errors? Also check the traffic in Fiddler for more information.

Comment: How can I detect the error and I haven't the correlation Id please? when I tried to play the video, no errors appeared, jut stay loading...

Comment: Have you use  the H.264 video codec and either MP3 or AAC audio?

Comment: No, I didn't use them! I just encode the wmv using Encoder Expression. Whe, it doesn't work, I converted the file to mp4 using ffmpeg.

Comment: Check this answer (#11) try the codec libx264 or x264 and see if one of them will work
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582602/ffmpeg-not-finding-vcodec-h264